# One big action or two small ones on Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I'm using **redux** for my react-native project. I have to use some Switch components(true or false) to select differents colors and save them into an array in the state. I can have an empty array or for example ["black","white"] according with my Switchs selection.

My question is if is better to have one action named "EDIT_COLOR" and inside it an "IF" statement to check if I'm adding or removing the color from the array, or have two actions one for adding and another one for removing.

Number one has the advantage of pass just one action to the components but the reducer get a little bigger with the IF statement inside.

Thanks a lot for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

As long as actions are manageable, create one reducer. However, if the actions functionalities are not related, then you should create separate reducers for each one. For instance, creating different reducers for user authentication and fetching data from an API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sam. I have a couple of reducers. But my question was regarding to if is better to have one action for editing the color, which leades in a bigger "case" inside the reducer with an if statement for dividing "add color" from "remove color" , or have two actions, one for adding and one for removing the color.